# Is there a formula for $(x+y+z)^n$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

We have that $$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k},$$
but is there such a formula for $(x+y+z)^n$ ?

Comment: Try to withdraw yourself, replacing y + z = t

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1008703, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74362, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/837346 – all found quickly with [Apporach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(x%2By%2Bz)%5En%24&p=3#) (but who cares)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).

In your case (3 variables), a bit of combinatronics yields:
$$
(x+y+z)^n=\sum_{k+l+m=n} \frac{n!}{k!l!m!}x^ky^lz^m
$$

Answer (score 5):

$$(x+y+z)^n=([x+y]+z)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(x+y)^kz^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\left[\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^jy^{k-j}\right]z^{n-k}$$

Answer (score 0):

There is::

$$(x+y+z)^n= \!\!\sum_{\substack{(i,j,k)\in\mathbf N^3\\i+j+k=n}}\!\frac{n!}{i!\,j!\,k!} x^i y^j z^k.$$
It can be extended to sums of more than $3$ terms (*multinomial formula*):
$$(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_r)^n= \!\!\sum_{\substack{(i_1,i_2,\dots, i_r)\in\mathbf N^r\\i_1+i_2+\dots+i_r=n}}\!\frac{n!}{i_1!\,i_2!\,\dotsm i_r!}\, x_1^{i_1} x_2^{i_2}\dotsm \,x_r^{i_r}.$$

Comment: Where is the difference to Bill's answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2773339/42969 above?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at the comments. You're right – none, except the variables exponents names. I'll remove it in a moment.